# Creating a log of redirected connection on a page

Tags: php, redirect, logging

I have a system which go get a file on my server.
To be able to easily change the file the system will get, I made a simple redirect on a php page.

But now I want to keep tracks of which and when system connect.
Each system now send their ID on GET when connecting to my page, but I m struggling to even write the file.

The link called is http://mysite.com/smtg/get.php?i=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

Which contain:

```php
<?
$fp = fopen('http://mysite.com/smtg/log.txt','a+');
    fseek($fp,SEEK_END);
    $w=$_GET['i']."\r\n";
    fputs($fp,$w);
    fclose($fp);

    header('Location: http://mysite.com/smtg/file.txt', true, 302);

exit();
?>
```

I ve even tried creating a empty file and putting it on the server, permission are 664, but it don t get updated.

The redirect work from browser and system thought.

EDIT:

When removing the redirect, I get:

```
test 
Warning: fopen(/smtg/log.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
    in /var/www/mysite.com/smtg/get.php on line 5 
Warning: fseek() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
    in /var/www/mysite.com/smtg/get.php on line 6 
Warning: fputs() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
    in /var/www/mysite.com/smtg/get.php on line 8 
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
    in /var/www/mysite.com/smtg/get.php on line 9
```

It seems it don t find the log file, but isn t it supposed to be created if missing?

The file is on the server, empty but here (http://mysite.com/smtg/log.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite simple, and coming directly from misunderstanding of the concepts related to filesystem hierarchy.

[Here I tried to write an answer explaining the matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3678513/285587), quite awkward though, but hope it will help to comprehend these matters. Especially why you can't use neither 'http://...' nor '/smtg/'

So, for the log you have to use

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/smtg/log.txt', $_GET['i'], FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Your link is really helpful to understand my mistake, and your solution is good, but I ll award the bounty to alvk4r, and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening a file handle on a HTTP resource:

```php
fopen('http://mysite.com/smtg/log.txt','a+');
```

Try using something like this:

```php
fopen('/smtg/log.txt','a+')
```

I'm pretty sure that you'll have problems using fputs on a file handle from a HTTP resource.

Comment: It seems that the problem is somewhere else, since I still don t get the log, but thanks for the tip

Comment: What errors are you getting? Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your page.

Comment: Done, but I don t see the output of theses nowhere

Comment: On Firefox console: [11:00:04,701] GET http://mysite.com/smtg/get.php [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 15ms]
[11:00:04,703] GET http://mysite.com/smtg/file.txt [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 16ms]

Comment: That error means that /rasp/log.txt doesn't exist. Make sure that your path is correct.

Comment: forgot to replace it by smtg, I ve checked if it exist, it does and is empty. But even if it don t exist, isn t fopen supposed to create it since I have 'a' argument? Also, why is there '/var/www/' before the link?

Comment: awww, don't open files from the disk root

Answer (score 1):

This work perfectly for me (trying `http://localhost/stackoverflow/logger.php?i=xxxx`):

logger.php

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_GET['i']))
{
    $text = date('H:m:s') . "\t \t \t" . $_GET['i'];
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/redirection-' . date('Y-m-d'). '.log', $text."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    header('Location: http://localhost/stackoverflow/file.txt', true, 302);
}
```

if you're using Linux be sure the apache user has writing privileges on directory where puts log file.