# CSS, JS, File access with realpath(dirname(__FILE__))

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

I searched but did not find a definitive answer for my question.

What is the best practice to include .css, .js, and other files?
How do I declare it in my configuration file. 
I tried :

```
define('CONST_ADMIN_JAVASCRIPT_LOCATION', 'jscript/');
```

This works but i think is most elegant to define like this in index.php:

```
define( 'ADMIN_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

And then the css directory :

```
define('CONST_ADMIN_CSS_LOCATION', ADMIN_ROOT.'templates/default/css/');
```

So if i try this then when including css, js, and other files then I get an error : 404 Not Found

```
<link href="/var/www/html/mysite/adminarea/templates/default/css/default_admin.css.php "    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The file is there so I'm thinking the .htaccess file restriction must be the problem.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# HTTP OVER SSL
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect non-www to www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Restricting direcotry listings
Options -Indexes

## RESTRICTING UPLOADS ONLY FOR IMAGE FILES
<Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.png|*.gif)>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

So what is the best practice solution for this problem ?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server/filesystem paths, and webserver/document_root-relative ones.

Comment: Thanks! This is sooo constructive :)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678351/php-realpath-function-question, as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240462/php-convert-file-system-path-to-url, and lastly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481629/how-do-i-set-base-url-for-all-pages-of-my-website

Comment: Much, much better, thank you :)